# Where can I store a batch file so it runs anywhere on my computer?

Tags: windows, path

I created a really small batch file that I want to be able to call anywhere in my command-line environment by name:

So if my batch file is hi.bat, I want to type hi in the command window and have it run. Where can i store the batch file so this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Store it somewhere in the PATH or have PATH include its directory. The PATH variable contains a list of directories that are searched when you enter a command. Depending on your version of windows, you can change environment variables from `My Computer -> Properties` or `Advanced System Settings`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the permissions, just modify the PATH environment variable to include the folder which hi.bat is in. You can then place hi.bat anywhere you want.